# OAuth credentials in secrets.yml in development section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, app-secret

My Rails app uses OAuth authentication. For production credentials, I use dotenv gem. config/secrets.yml:

```yaml
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
  facebook_app_id: <%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] %>
  facebook_app_secret: <%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'] %>
```

For testing, I use specially registered Facebook app that has "redirect_uri" to http://localhost.

Should I use the same approach for "development" section or I can write creds of apps that are registered for testing? How I understand no one can use it (for fishing websites) because there is "redirect_uri" that pointing on "localhost" in the settings of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended not to expose the creds, even for the testing. You should follow the same approach for both dev and test. Also, add your file containing all the credentials to `.gitignore`

Comment: Can you explain why it's recommended? It's easier to distribute the open source app in the such form (when there are testing creds). Other developers can run a test suite faster.

Comment: The case is different when it's open source. For private repos, you don't want to expose the information about your application, and that is the reason it is recommended not to expose the creds.